# Установка bootstrap.scss без npm

Tags: bootstrap, scss

возможно вопрос тупой, но на моём уровне развития справиться одному мне сложно.
Есть простенький одностраничник, к нему подключено пара скриптов и bootstrap.css, так вот, мне нужно переопределить львиную долю классов и переменных, хочется работать исключительно с scss , а не с css.

По сути мне нужна папка bootstrap в которой находится набор из scss файлов типа _variables.scss _mixins.scss и тд и тп, но при поиске такой папки в интернете я ничего не смог найти. Гуглил bootstrap scss мне выдаёт кучу вариантов , но которые устанавливаются через менеджер пакетов, а мне нужна просто папка со всеми файлами из которой я смогу импортировать нужные, проект мизерный, подтягивать сборщики типа webpack просто смешно. Помогите.
Спасибо.

Comment: Можете просто скачать [сорс файлы с официального сайта](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/#source-files)

Comment: Блин, спасибо) Нашел!

Comment: Удосужтесь промотать к заголовку SOURCE FILES.